# Rails 4 + PostgreSQL (Heroku): complex/scalable queries for analysis/reporting on data

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, schema, reporting

Working on a financial application that tracks sales.  However, I'm running into problems trying to create a schema for properly tracking the data for reports (the main point of the app).

A `purchase` is the foundation of the app.  It has several associations (listed below).  Each `purchase` is tracked via a year and month field.  A year is the smallest unit a user may filter a report by, so I will only have to show data for each month in that year.

```
# purchase.rb model
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Associations:
  # belongs_to :partner
  # belongs_to :purchase_type
  # belongs_to :purchase_category

  # Attributes:
  # partner_id           => association
  # purchase_type_id     => association
  # purchase_category_id => association
  # year                 => year in integer (2013, 2014, etc...)
  # month                => month in integer ("January" => 1, etc...)
  # amount               => amount a product sold for in cents ($10.00 => 1000)
  # fee                  => fee for associated partner (if there is one) in cents ($2.00 => 200)
end
```

The problem is that I need to show an overview for a given year, which breaks things down by how many purchases were completed, what partners completed them, and what were the fee amounts.  I solved that by having `YearMetric` and `MonthMetric` tables that are updated everytime a purchase is added/updated/removed.  So you add a new purchase for a given year/month, and the corresponding `YearMetric` and `MonthMetric` rows are found and updated with +/- the appropriate amounts/fees.

This solution works well for the overview page.  However, I also need to be able to view purchases in the context of partners, purchase_types, and purchase_categories.  If I followed the same strategy as my overview report, I would have to add the following tables:

- PartnerYearMetric, PartnerMonthMetric
- PurchaseCategoryYearMetric, PurchaseCategoryMonthMetric
- PurchaseTypeYearMetric, PurchaseTypeMonthMetric

So everytime I add a purchase, I would be doing up to 8 additional DB updates (8 finds and then 8 updates).

The items I'm reporting on are total purchases made, average purchases (historical comparison), total amounts/fees for the period, top partners by number of purchases and by most fee amounts, etc...

There has to be a better solution than this.  "Live calculation" by updating 8 records for every 1 purchase seems a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is maintaining materialized views of the data in the application. It's a form of denormalization. That can be OK as an optimization but should not be your first choice. It can be very error prone, especially in the presence of concurrency, and must be done quite carefully.

Instead, when you wish to generate a summary report, use an aggregate to `SUM` them, `COUNT` them, etc as appropriate. See [aggregate functions in the Pg docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html), [rails Calculations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html), [rails aggregates](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/ActiveRecord/Aggregations).

You may find it convenient to create a `VIEW` over the query you use, and then access the view from the application.

*If* you find performance of calculating the aggregates in real time for the summary to be a problem, and you cannot solve it with proper indexing and tuning, *then* you should think about denormalizing. Rather than maintaining your materialized views in the app, though, consider using triggers in the database; they're much easier to write in a concurrency-safe way.

You may also want to look up PostgreSQL 9.4's enhanced materialized views support.

Comment: Good advice on DB triggers and views. I'm used to working with an Oracle DBA who figures out these things, but on this app I'm doing the DB work myself. Hence the reason I've shied away from DB solutions. My main concern is that users will look at 5-10 reports in a given session, and each report will have about 20 DB queries across all the account's data to get the stats for the report. With 1,000 concurrent users, that seemed like it would lead to slow page loads. My goal is to get each report page to load in 1 sec or less. Do you think it's feasible to scale PG like this?

Comment: @DanL Depends on the hardware and whether the DB fits in RAM or not. It sounds like it's probably a candidate for materialized views, likely trigger-maintained ones, but you can do it in the app too if you're careful about concurrency.